# Generate public, private using ECDH and nodejs crypto

Tags: node.js, sqlite, cryptography, diffie-hellman

When a new User is added to ldap client, I want to generate a keypair for him with nodejs crypto and store it to sqlite3.

My code to add a new User is:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('create new user');
  console.log(req.body);

  var cn = req.body.cn;
  var employeeType = req.body.employeeType;
  var password = req.body.password;

 ldap.addUser(cn, employeeType, password);

 var alice = crypto.creadeECDH('secp256k1');
 var keyPair = alice.generateKeys();
 db.addKeypairs(cn, keyPair);

  res.sendStatus(201);
});
```

Should be something like db.addKeypairs but I don't know how to store it to sqlite3. Does anyone know how to?